# angular 2 - HTTP get request parameter special characters are gone

Tags: angular, http-get

i am trying to make HTTP get call with some parameters. The param vsLoginToken has the value '0D+92VVcZNFde+AWbHA'.

```
let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('tenantId', tenantId);
params.set('branchId', branchId);
params.set('vsLoginToken', vsLoginToken);

this._http.get(url, { search: params }).map(res => res.json()).
  catch(error => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
```

But when i process this param in the server side the value is '0D 92VVcZNFde    AWbHA'. As you can see the two '+' characters are replaced with spaces. Can any one help me on this? Thanks

Comment: read here [https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11058](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11058)

Answer (score 0):

The `+` sign is a special character in URLs as it substitutes a whitespace. You need to URL-encode it, which will turn it into `%2B`.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Answer (score 0):

In the official documentation of URLSearchParams, it explicitly states the following

```
These are the characters that are not encoded: ! $ \' ( ) * + , ; A 9 - . _ ~ ? /
```

the official documentation also includes how to use a queryencoder if necessary.
please refer to https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/URLSearchParams-class.html